# Cuando le envio mi json al data de mi datatable mediante angular no me los imprime en el navegador

Tags: angular, datatables

Actualmente quiero rellenar mi `datatable` con un json que recibe de un webservice pero no se imprime de forma correcta:

Error de Impresión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en la que el JSON es enviado es la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en que trato de obtener el json es la siguiente:

Código component.ts

```
ngOnInit () {
    this._peticionesService.getArticulos().subscribe(
            result => {
                    console.log(result.data);
                            this.dtOption = {
            "data":result.data,
        "columns":[
            { title: "idUser" },
            { title: "Nick" },
            { title: "Password" }
            ]
    };
    this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
    this.dataTable.DataTable(this.dtOption);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error en una ventana:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes hacer un `console.log(typeof result.data)`, para saber qué te arroja? El problema pudiese estar en que estás pasando un tipo diferente al esperado por el atributo `data`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo hice y me salio como resultado object, es el tipo correcto?

Comment: Pues creo que no, si bien los datos de cada registro son de tipo object, según la [documentación](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects), los mismos son elementos de un tipo `Array`. ¿Puedes probar pasando los datos así: `"data": [result.data]`? y comentas los resultados. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras me salio el siguiente resulto [object Object] dentro de los rows de la tabla.

Comment: Pues el tema es lo que te devuelve tu `result`, es extraño, la salida que muestras en la imagen se corresponde con el tipo de dato que está esperando, pero el error que bota indica que hay algo diferente o que no concuerda.

Comment: Viendo bien, me parece que tienes un error de `typo`, cambia `$(this.table.nativeElement);` por `$(this.Table.nativeElement);`, con la letra T mayúscula en la palabra `Table`. Y deja el atributo `data` como lo tenías. (sin los corchetes). A ver si es eso.

Comment: @MauricioContreras  ya lo hice pero me salio  "this.Table is undefined" porque table es una variable que tengo como  @ViewChild('dataTable') table.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93245/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-david).